# Angular Passing One Component to Other Component

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I am basically trying to pass one component to other component in the template. 
I have created a new ng project via `ng new new-proj`

and this is my code

```
//contents inside app.component.html

<app-g-table [inputVariable] = "data"> //Table Component
  <app-g-column [name]="'Employee'"></app-g-column> //Column Component
</app-g-table>

 I need to get the data of Column Component[app-g-column] (in this example 
 'Employee') inside app-g-table.ts
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

---

**UPDATE**
1. I am developing my own generic data table, which can be implemented by using the syntax as above.
2. In the above example, I will be passing the list of column components eventually,
like this

```
 <app-g-table [inputVariable] = "data"> //Table Component
      <app-g-column [name]="'Employee'" [isVisible]="true"></app-g-column> //Column Component
      <app-g-column [name]="'Age'" [isVisible]="false"></app-g-column> //Column Component
</app-g-table>
```

I was wondering if I can directly use components (app-g-column) inside (app-g-table) directly?

Comment: Please describe your question properly.

Comment: I need something line <ng-content> but instead of dom I am passing a list of components as a parameter

Comment: Can you stalcbiltz your code here. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ywnxx

Answer (score 1):

I have shared the solution to your question.
Check here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xuxd7a

OR

First, create a sharedService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  Subject  } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  myData: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {}

  setData(data) {
    this.myData.next(data);
  }
}
```

Then from where you want to set the data use this method:

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.sharedService.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Then in your Component2 where you want to display the data:

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.sharedService.myData.subscribe((value) => {
     console.log(value) // Here you will get your complete data
    });
  }
```

}

Comment: I need this function in parent-component, not in app-component  
                   getDataFromChild(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                       this.myData = data;
                  }

Comment: I have shared another approach as well

Comment: Thanks for your help, your solution of passing the data between multiple components via a service is working, however I am hoping for different approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

in order to pass data between components in Angular, you should use Input and Output, there is a link below that it can help you find the deep understanding of passing data and event between component:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: if you see my question, I am passing <app-g-column> as a parameter to component <app-g-table>. I need a placeholder in app-g-table to capture the variables used in app-g-columns.

Comment: The parent component in this example is app.component.html, so passing data via parent-child component is not helping

Comment: if you want to pass data between components, you should use observables and Subject in rxjs library

Comment: check this please :  https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-subjects-339428a1815b